# Why are those algorithm so different in term of their execution time ? Is the walrus operator less time consuming in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, python-assignment-expression

While making a function to manipulate the `TypeVar` from the **typing module**, I came across a problem.
My function do work but I wanted to make it faster so I used the **timeit module** to test some different versions.
However the result aren't what I expected.

---

**Clearing some potential interrogation :**

`check_type(object , type)` is a function meant to test if an object correspond to a type (quite time consuming currently).

`isTypeVar(type)` test if type is a TypeVar.

`NullType` is a type that cannot describe an object so when it's tested with `check_type` it always return False.

`restrict_TypeVar_for_object(typeVar , object)` is the function that I have made in order to remove all of the constraints of my typeVar that doesn't correspond to object.

How I time my functions :

```
from timeit import timeit

func_version = """..."""
task="""..."""
timeit(task , setups=func_version , number=10_000_000)
```

Here is the task that I have timed (as you can see above **I have repeated it 10 000 000 times**) :

```
Number = int | float
T = TypeVar("T" , int , str , Number)

restrict_TypeVar_for_object(T , 5)
#   --> TypeVar("T" , int , Number)
```

---

**My test :**

- 1st version :

```
def restrict_TypeVar_for_object(ty , obj):
    if not isTypeVar(ty) : #Just to be sure that ty is a TypeVar
        raise ValueError ('Expected a TypeVar as an argument')

    if not ty.__constraints__ :
        return type(obj)

    lCons=[cons for cons in ty.__constraints__ if check_type(obj , cons)]
    return (TypeVar(ty.__name__ , *lCons)
            if len(lCons)>1 else
            lCons[0]
            if lCons else
            NullType)
```

Takes : **378.5483768 s**

- 2nd version :

```
def restrict_TypeVar_for_object(ty , obj):
    if not isTypeVar(ty) : #Just to be sure that ty is a TypeVar
        raise ValueError ('Expected a TypeVar as an argument')

    if not ty.__constraints__ :
        return type(obj)

    return (TypeVar(ty.__name__ , *lCons)
            if len(lCons:=[cons for cons in ty.__constraints__ if check_type(obj , cons)])>1 else
            lCons[0]
            if lCons else
            NullType)
```

Takes : **376.9706139 s**

- 3rd version :

```
def restrict_TypeVar_for_object(ty , obj):
    if not isTypeVar(ty) : #Just to be sure that ty is a TypeVar
        raise ValueError ('Expected a TypeVar as an argument')

    if not ty.__constraints__ :
        return type(obj)

    return (TypeVar(ty.__name__ , *lCons[:-1])
            if len(lCons:=[c for c in ty.__constraints__ if check_type(obj,c)]+[NullType]) > 2
            else
            lCons[0])
```

Takes : **391.5145658000001 s**

---

As you can see **the 2nd one is the quickest**.
However I wasn't expecting the 3rd one to be that slow compared to the other.
To be frank I was even expecting it to be the quickest one because I did less if statement in this  one.

I have 2 hypothesis for why this is the case :

-First, the walrus operator but if it is, why is the 2nd version the quickest.

-Second, the fact that I add `[NullType]` at the end of `lCons` but I don't know why it would be this time consuming.

Comment: You are creating more lists in that last one. `lCons[:-1]` is a new list. and adding `+[NullType]` is both the [NullType] list and then the new list for the concatenation. That's the lists and the extra refcounting for the contents.

Comment: I see I didn't thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as **tdelaney** pointed out, **the difference in term of their execution time comes from the creation of many list** in the 3rd version :

- `[c for c in ty.__constraints__ if check_type(obj,c)]` which is common to all version.
- `[NullType]`, the list resulting from the concatenation `lCons + [NullType]` and `lCons[:-1]` which are exclusive to the 3rd version.

---

Now comes the 2nd part of my question, about **the time consumption of the walrus operator**.

The walrus operator takes more time than a simple assignation as shown by the test below :

```
from timeit import timeit

#Assignement statement :
tsk1="""
a = 5
"""

#Assignement expression :
tsk2="""
(a := 5)
"""

print(timeit(tsk1 , number=10_000_000))
print(timeit(tsk2 , number=10_000_000))
```

tsk1 repeated 10 000 000 takes : **0.7440573999992921 s**

tsk2 repeated 10 000 000 takes : **1.0597749000007752 s**

*I did the test many time and the result are always approximately the same.*

---

Finally, here is how I should implement my `restrict_TypeVar_for_object(typeVar , object)` function in Python :

```
def restrict_TypeVar_for_object(ty , obj):
    if not isTypeVar(ty) : #Just to be sure that ty is a TypeVar
        raise ValueError ('Expected a TypeVar as an argument')

    if not ty.__constraints__ :
        return type(obj)
    
    lCons = [cons for cons in ty.__constraints__ if check_type(obj , cons)]
    return (TypeVar(ty.__name__ , *lCons)
            if len(lCons)>1 else
            [*lCons , NullType][0])
```

Which, repeated 10 000 000 times takes : **383.57044309999765**

However as you can see  it still takes too much time so I have tried with the walrus operator :

```
def restrict_by_object(ty , obj):
    if not isTypeVar(ty) : #Just to be sure that ty is a TypeVar
        raise ValueError ('Expected a TypeVar as an argument')

    if not ty.__constraints__ :
        return type(obj)

    return (TypeVar(ty.__name__ , *lCons)
            if len(lCons:=[cons for cons in ty.__constraints__ if check_type(obj , cons)])>1 else
            [*lCons , NullType][0])
```

This takes : **373.867099199997 s**

*I still don't know why the walrus operator is better in this case but will update this answer once I understand it.*